# PHP Сравнение многомерных массивов с разной вложенностью

Tags: php, modx, pdo

Есть два массива, первый имеет вид:

```
[0]=> { ["AAA"]=>"123" ["BBB"]=>"11" }
[1]=> { ["AAA"]=>"321" ["BBB"]=>"13" }
```

Второй массив выглядит так:

```
[0]=> { ["aaa"]=>"123" }
[1]=> { ["aaa"]=>"111" }
```

Нужно сравнить ["AAA"] и ["aaa"], если во втором массиве нет значения из первого, то записать ["AAA"] и ["BBB"] в новый массив.

Comment: modx? pdo? разная вложенность?

Comment: и что пишется в  ["BBB"] в новый массив?

Comment: @Ипатьев пишется такаяже структура элементов как в первом массиве

Comment: @vp_arth д мне хоть на чистом php хотябы это сделать

Answer (score 0):

Для этой задачи подойдет функция `array_diff_key();`, в итоге получаем:

```
$arr_new = array_diff_key($arr_one, $arr_two);
```

В результате в массив `$arr_new` запишется `[1]=> { ["AAA"]=>"321" ["BBB"]=>"13" }`